# Unable to add Tabs inside Fragment of Navigation Drawer Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, navigation-drawer

**1)** I have followed the *Navigation Drawer example in Android Developer Docs* here 
[developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)
and created my whole application. In the given example, they have used Fragments for each item selected in the Drawer called fragments with following code

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("Title_Number", position);
fragment.setArguments(args);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

**2)** Now I want a **Tab behavior inside a Fragment** i.e., when I select a particular item in the Nav-Drawer, the Fragment loaded should display a Tab bar on the top something like this. http://flic.kr/p/hn4G3i

**3)** I have followed the tutorial and example given here 
[developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html), 
but the example given here is using **FragmentActivity** which is not compatible with Fragments (as per my knowledge).

Could someone help me achieving this behaviour in my app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u got the solution , if yes please post the solutiuoiin here .... I am also doing an app somewhat like this and need to add a tabhost inside fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import cgg.gov.in.apps.eoffice.source.R;

public class TestTabsinsideFragment extends Fragment
{
    View rootView;

public TestTabsinsideFragment () 
{
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState)
{   

getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// Apply the layout for the fragment
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.approve_leaves, container, false);


getActivity().setTitle("New tabbed layout inside Fragment :-) ");


ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // show the given tab
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // hide the given tab
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // probably ignore this event
    }
};

// Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++) {
    getActivity().getActionBar().addTab(
            getActivity().getActionBar().newTab()
            .setText("Tab " + (i1 + 1))
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
}


return rootView;
}
```

I have fixed the problem myself. :D

Comment: I tried implementing what you have done here. But did you notice that now, if you navigate to another drawer fragment and come back, it creates 3 tab items each time. How do fix that? Also, the tabs seem to overlay the drawer when it should be the opposite.How did you fix these issues?

Comment: Yes. Mr. Bhalla, I have faced the same issues. I dont know how to fix them, I ended changing my design.

Comment: I guess, Google Android code repository will have code for creating such behavior(This behavior is there in PlayStore). But then I couldn't get the code for PlayStore, its confidential I guess ;-)